# ADB timed Out Error in Appium(Android) using Java

Tags: android, appium

This is my code. It should open the browser navigate to google and should type "Appium" in the search box.
It opens the chrome browser and navigates to the google, but after that it shows the error directly, after waiting for few seconds.

```
public class androidDevice {

AppiumDriver driver;
@BeforeTest
public void Appium_device() throws MalformedURLException, Exception {
    {

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();


          capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "43f0a801");

          capabilities.setCapability("chromedriverExecutable", "D:\\Soumya\\Eclipse\\chromedriver.exe");


            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "8.1.0");

          capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");

         capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.chrome");
         capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main");



          driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"),capabilities);

           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
    }
    @Test    
    public void launch() throws Exception {
              try {
    //driver.get("https://us.justdial.com");
                  driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                driver.findElement(By.id("com.android.chrome:id/search_box_text")).sendKeys("Appium");
                  driver.quit();

    System.out.println("site hit");
}
catch (Exception e) { 
    System.out.println("site not accessed");
    throw (e);
    // TODO: handle exception
}

          }
```

}

The expected result is: It should open the browser navigate to google and should type "Appium" in the search box.

Actual Result: 
Appium Result

```
FAILED: launch org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown
 server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original
 error: Error attempting to start URI. Original error: Error: Error
 executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command
'C\:\\Users\\soumya.katti\\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P
 5037 -s 43f0a801 shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d
 https\://us.justdial.com com.android.chrome' timed out after 20000ms';
 Stderr: ''; Code: 'null' (WARNING: The server did not provide any
 stacktrace information)
```

Eclipse Result:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error attempting to start URI. Original error: Error: Error executing adbExec. Original error: 'Command 'C\:\\Users\\soumya.katti\\android-sdks\\platform-tools\\adb.exe -P 5037 -s 43f0a801 shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d https\://us.justdial.com com.android.chrome' timed out after 20000ms'; Stderr: ''; Code: 'null' (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 40.05 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got an implicit wait of 30 seconds. This means that the WebDriver has 30 seconds to find a certain element defined in the DOM. If it doesn't in such time, the test fails with the exception you have shown. If the process times out while trying to perform a task, then it is likely that you can fix this by increasing the implicit wait:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

set to 60, 120 or a reasonable amount of time based on your experience with this tests.

Do notice that the implicit wait is for each command to the WebDriver, not for the whole test, so it shouldn't really be so large.

Another possibility is that the item you're looking for isn't really found in the page layout. Maybe it is not visible at the moment, maybe you're in a different scren than the one you expect.

Check carefully the execution of the test case to see what happens. Try to add some timers to see when the implicit wait is beginning.

You can learn more about implicit and explicit waits at [WebDriver: Advanced Usage](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) and [Implicit Wait - Appium](http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/session/timeouts/implicit-wait/).

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't work. I also tried to remove the find elements code and if directly try with driver.close it still shows the same error as before.